# Solve this riddle: Twelve smooth pebbles

Tags: riddle

I wrote my first riddle.

> Twelve smooth pebbles sit facing the sky,
>
> With one large roof, keeping them dry.
>
> Listens and speaks at the same time,
>
> Knows every secret, both yours and mine.
>
> Used by billions, invented by two,
>
> Older than most, but wiser than few.

What is it?

Comment: A title something like "Twelve smooth pebbles" might be better. The current title is vague and indistinguishable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a...

> telephone

**Twelve smooth pebbles sit facing the sky,**

> it has 12 keys (including * and #)

**With one large roof, keeping them dry.**

> *(not sure)* the plastic between keys themselves?

**Listens and speaks at the same time,
Knows every secret, both yours and mine.**

> You can both talk and listen

**Used by billions, invented by two,**

> Many people have telephones, but it was invented by Meucci and/or Graham Bell

**Older than most, but wiser than few.**

> Everyone alive now was born after it was invented and it is not wise because it only transports voice, it's doesn't know anything

Comment: Not *everyone* has one, but other than this you're probably right! [\pedant]

Comment: @randal'thor doesnt have to be used by everyone? just billions.

Comment: Let's say that, on average, everyone has one :D

Comment: @Oblongamous - Andrea said 'everyone' under one of the spoilertags, but has now changed it :-)

Comment: @randal'thor problem resolved :).

Comment: Wow, well done, certainly didn't expect it to be solved that quick. The "one large roof, keeping them dry" is meant to be the handset, traditionally resting above the buttons - http://www.bmstores.co.uk/images/hpcProductImage/imgFull/285443-Optimum-Home-Phone-Black.jpg

Comment: I didn't consider it because if the pebbles/keys face the sky, the handset is not a roof :P

Comment: I was thinking a flip (clamshell) phone -- definitely older than "most" since the patent for it goes back to the 70s, and fits well with the roof clue. Arguable if it's been used by billions, but I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @AndreaGottardi ...looks like I need to work on my wording. Good point.

Comment: @reokatoa interpretation is a good one :D didn't think about it

Comment: @reokatoa Erm... everyone pretend that I meant that please.